# End User Migration Tools

Tags: migration, web-services

I am looking for a tool that would allow end users to migrate SharePoint content.

Mandatory:

- Works across ALL SharePoint platforms (2003, 2007, 2010)
- works for document libraries and lists

Nice to have:

- migrates history/versions
- keeps columns/metadata values, in particular the Modified and Modified By fields.

I am looking for a solution beyond copy/paste or drag'n drop.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many administrative type migration tools (Idera, for example), but nothing really geared toward end users.

Answer (score 0):

If it's stil relevant for you, I can suggest a professional tool from http://www.tzunami.com

David.

Comment: David, could you be more specific? I need a tool for end users, no server side access.